# Meaning of paragraph

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read "[The myth of Main Street](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/04/08/opinion/sunday/the-myth-of-main-street.html?_r=0)" by David Opdyke in the April 8, 2017 issue of *The New York Times*. There is one paragraph:

> Americans, regardless of education or geographical location, have marketable skills in the global economy: They speak English and understand the nuances of communicating with Americans — something that cannot be easily shipped overseas. The United States remains the largest consumer market in the world, and Americans can (and some already do) sell these services abroad.

1. *Something that cannot be easily shipped overseas* means *the work can not be easily got by overseas persons as they don't master the language*? Does *something" refer to nuances or the language skill?
2. What does *these services* refer to?
3. The author says US remains the largest consumer market in the world, I think author says this which must relate to the topic— small-town Americans can find jobs? but I don't know how they relate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like an attempt to get help with an exercise, and shows no signs of effort.

Comment: What do you mean by"shows no signs of effort"?Haven't I made any effort to think over it and try to solve it? You are wrong. The answer by Satnam is greatly helpful. I improve my English here , and I appreciate it. But what you say is not a reply to question but make me confused. To get help for a exercise means what? Yes, I read and exercise and improve my English. This is what I always do here, I help to answer others' questions also. What is wrong with my raising my question?

Comment: If you have indeed made some efforts into solving the problems yourself, you should [edit] and include those efforts, or this question might get closed.

Comment: I have edited it to include how my understanding conflict and why I am not clear. I do the same --to show the way how I understand it when next time I have aquestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Something" refers to the **marketable skills** that the Americans possess, specifically the ones that are mentioned viz their ability to speak English and understand the nuances of communication with Americans.

"These services" also refer to those marketable skills. Americans can provide services to the rest of the world like helping them to communicate with a large consumer market, that is America.

> Many rural Americans, sadly, don’t realize how valuable they already are or what opportunities presently exist for them. It’s true that the digital economy, centered in a few high-tech cities, has left Main Street America behind. But it does not need to be this way. Today, for the first time, thanks to the internet, small-town America can pull back money from Wall Street (and big cities more generally). Through global freelancing platforms like Upwork, for example, rural and small-town Americans can find jobs anywhere in world, using abilities and talents they already have. A receptionist can welcome office visitors in San Francisco from her home in New York’s Finger Lakes. Through an e-commerce website like Etsy, an Appalachian woodworker can create custom pieces and sell them anywhere in the world.

This paragraph gives many examples how the fact that America is the largest consumer market is conducive to small-town Americans finding jobs anywhere in the world. Basically, it implies that even small-town Americans have the skills to find jobs in this age and America (along with the rest of the world) provide a ready market for those skills.